# vim: undo newline in insert mode?

Tags: vim, undo

I often accidentally press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while typing in insert mode. To undo the accidental new line, I typically press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> several times, first to remove all the automatic indentation, and then, finally, to remove the accidental new line.

Is there a better way to achieve this?  Perhaps something like undoing the effects of the last pressed key?

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for! Why don't you type it up as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Xavier Could you consider undeleting your answer? TIMTOWTDI, let's see the alternatives! (Or perhaps, you could explain why the approach is bad, in your opinion?)

Comment: There are good answers already, but it can be good to know that in insert mode the `<Del>` key (under `<Insert>` key) also joins lines if you are at the end of a line, so if you hit `<CR>` by accident you can just `<Up><End><Del>`, if often do that. (In normal mode you can't get to the position after the last, so there it doesn't work).

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77959482/22330192) below for how to solve this issue by making undoing in insert mode more granular.  Very useful stuff.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the exact same situation, I do `<C-w><C-w>`. `<C-w>` is a great asset to have in insert mode.

Comment: TIL! Another observation: after finally leveraging the true power of Ex commands for a year, I discover that lesser-known insert-mode bindings might be my next ---blind spot--- underestimated strength of Vim to tackle!

Comment: @sehe, *I don't believe you.*

Comment: @romainl You know, I don't do much in insert mode, other than... you know, insert keys/registers. And various completion keys obviously. The rest is so well-covered in Vim, I really hardly found the need to look for insert-mode equivalents. (The use-case from the OP is one exception, though)

Comment: I grew the habit of using `<C-w>` when I mistype something. I can't say I've discovered it myself: I was pointed at it by someone in some blog post's comment section.

Comment: but how can I redo in insert mode?

Answer (score 7):

`CTRL-W` deletes the last word typed. If you have typed several words or the identation level is deep `CTRL-U` might be an even better fit for your need, as it deletes everything you typed in the current insert mode session.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the "u" command for undo. If you're in INSERT mode just press "Ctrl+C" to stop inserting and then "u" and hit enter.

Does this work for you?

*Btw, to redo the changes use "Ctrl+R"..*

Comment: `u` also reverts whatever you inserted in the line above before hitting `<CR>`.

Comment: Thanks, but as romainl points out, I then loose what I typed before the newline.

Comment: You could use the following mapping: `inoremap <cr> <c-g>u<cr>` to break the undo sequence and start a new change right before the return.

Comment: Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77959482/22330192), which expands on the Peter's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an excerpt from my `~/.vimrc` that answers the OP's question and does a bit more.  The comments included in the vimscript code should make the whole thing pretty much self explanatory.

```
" Make each new line entered in insert mode separately undoable,
" instead of only being able to undo the entire chunks of new lines,
" but only when not in the command window
"
inoremap <silent> <expr> <CR> getcmdwintype() ==# "" ? "<C-G>u<CR>" : "<CR>"
```

With this remapping in place, each line entered in insert mode becomes separately undoable, including the accidental presses of <kbd>Enter</kbd> that the OP complained about.  Just hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit insert mode and then press <kbd>u</kbd> repeatedly to undo the desired number of accidental keypresses.  Redoing the keypresses will be available by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

The same remapping can also be additionally applied to the `<BS>` and `<Del>` keypresses (i.e. the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> keys, respectively), to make undoing in insert mode even more granular.